# Keras: .predict returns percentages instead of classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a model with 3 classes: `[0,1,2]`
After training, the `.predict` function returns a list of percentages instead. 
I was checking the keras documentation but could not figure out, what I did wrong.
`.predict_classes` is not working anymore, and I did not have this problem with previous classifiers. I already tried different activation functions (relu, sigmoid etc.)
If I understand correctly, the number in`Dense(3...)` defines the amount of classes.

```
outputs1=Dense(3,activation='softmax')(att_out) 
model1=Model(inputs1,outputs1)
model1.summary()
model1.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
model1.fit(x=text_pad,y=train_y,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=1,shuffle=True) 

y_pred = model1.predict(test_text_matrix)
```

Output example:

```
[[0.34014237 0.33570153 0.32415614]
 [0.34014237 0.33570153 0.32415614]
 [0.34014237 0.33570153 0.32415614]
 [0.34014237 0.33570153 0.32415614]
 [0.34014237 0.33570153 0.32415614]]
```

Output I want:

```
[1,2,0,0,0,1,2,0]
```

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not do anything wrong, `predict` has always returned the output of the model, for a classifier this has always been probabilities per class.

`predict_classes` is only available for `Sequential` models, not for Functional ones.

But there is an easy solution, you just need to take the `argmax` on the last dimension and you will get class indices:

```
y_probs = model1.predict(test_text_matrix)
y_pred  = np.argmax(y_probs, axis=-1)
```